# Not Able to import the FBInstant (Use of unresolved identifier 'FBInstant')

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fbsdk, facebook-instant-games

I want to use the FBInstant in my ios project

I have added pod file's to my project

pod 'FBSDKShareKit'

pod 'FacebookSDK'

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'

pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'

I want to use this function of FBInstant

```
var connectedPlayers = FBInstant.player.getConnectedPlayersAsync()
        .then(function(players) {
            console.log(players.map(function(player) {
                return {
                    id: player.getID(),
                    name: player.getName(),
                }
            }));
        });
```

I tried to import packages but didn't find FBInstant package it gives error

Use of unresolved identifier 'FBInstant'

I was following this [FBInstant link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/getting-started/quickstart)

But no luck so far

Comment: Have you updated your pods?

Comment: yes installed the latest one

Comment: Try removing and reinstalling the pods.

Comment: @Clint the issue is same